# Click function only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have these two simple js functions :

```
CTCC.Transactions.PieceRecuClick = function (source) {
    $(".chk input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
}

CTCC.Transactions.PieceNonRecuClick = function (source) {
    $(".chk input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
}
```

These affect the same checkboxes, a lot of CheckBoxes that all look like :

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Class="chk" ID="chkPieceJust" Text="Recues" Enabled="true" Checked="<%# CheckBoxChecked(Container.DataItem as Transaction) %>" />
```

When i click on ("put to true") it works the first time, but only the first time... I can push lots of time on ("put to false") and it always work. It's not a big issue, not at all, but i'm being curious about that strange behaviour. here, my html content after i push the "true" button (note that it's always the same after i push it, but it changes the checkboxes only the first time)

```
<input id="notUseful" type="checkbox" name="NotUseful" checked="checked">
```

This is how i call the functions:

```
   <input id="chkAllPieceJust" type="button" value="Mettre toutes les pièces justificatives à «Recues» " onclick="CTCC.Transactions.PieceRecuClick(this);" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input id="chkAllPieceJust2" type="button" value="Mettre toutes les pièces justificatives à «Non-Recues» " onclick="CTCC.Transactions.PieceNonRecuClick(this);" />
```

Comment: set the attr to 'checked' instead of true? as you show in your html?

Comment: lol, i tried, it's exactly the same behaviour, it work only the first time, i wonder if the binding affect checkbox behaviour...

Comment: No, i even removed the binding and it does not change anything

Comment: This dosen't make any sense, if the HTML content says it is checked, IT SHOULD BE CHECKED !!!!

Comment: just as a question, how/where do you call those functions? did you check the console, is there a reload happening? Is it visibly unchecked or when you request the value from the server side?

Comment: Have you tried `.prop`..?

Comment: @Icepickle i edited the question so you can see how i call those function, and it's only visibility the reel problem

Comment: @tymeJV seems like prop worked... i'm completely lost, can you post an answer explaining why prop works better than attr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tymeJV answered me in the comments, i now use .prop funtion instead of .attr and it work perfectly.